# Is it correct to use Java interfaces to represent nouns AND adjectives?

Tags: java, interface, encapsulation

I'm running into a problem understanding the semantics of Java's interfaces. I am modeling a problem with interfaces before I fill them in with code. I do this by seeking out the nouns in the problem and creating an interface for them, for example:

> Every house has at least one person in it. Each house may also contain exactly one bicycle and may contain at least one car.

So, I would create the interfaces IHouse, IPerson, and IVehicle (since we may have different types of houses, peoples, and vehicles in the future).

The problem comes when I get into the adjectives of these nouns, for example:

> Each house, bicycle, and car may have a certain color.

Instead of creating the following methods in each vehicle and house class, I create the following interface:

```
public interface IPainted {

    public Paint getPaint();

    public void setPaint();

}
```

and apply it to the vehicle and house interfaces:

```
public interface IVehicle extends IPainted {
}
```

Is this the best way of representing adjectives?

Comment: 'best' is subjective... but this is a fine way.

Comment: I think it is right, but the setPaint method probably will be void an with a Paint argument

Comment: Just to add, you may find the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) interesting while learning about interfaces and abstract classes.

Comment: I also found this: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?InterfacesShouldBeAdjectives

Comment: Using `I` in front of interface names http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814805/java-interfaces-implementation-naming-convention/2814831#2814831

Comment: I can appreciate the argument but some people correctly point out that a Vehicle interface is not exactly a Vehicle (class). Rather, it's a blueprint for a Vehicle. When the English equivalent presents itself (in this case Vehicle works nicely to represent an abstraction of Bicycle and Car) the I seems needless. However, when there is no suitable English word for the abstract (think IPerson and Person) then I feel as though the I may be necessary.

Comment: @sdasdadas Then perhaps you should put `C` in front of all class names

Comment: @SteveKuo That doesn't follow at all. The point that I was making is that sometimes it is impossible to name an interface without an I, because the English (or the domain) language doesn't allow for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. And to put both of your somewhat awkward designations of "noun" and "adjective" in the same bucket, use suffix "able" -- in this case `public interface Paintable`.  So all the properties of a paintable class **that have to do with paintability** should be encapsulated within the `Paintable` interface which that class implements.

Comment: Thank you - the naming conventions works for things such as Paintable, Selectable, Identifiable, etc. but what happens if each Vehicle contains a list of its parts? It can't be named IPartable...that's where I find the *able naming convention goes out the IWindow.

Comment: `Vehicle` should be an abstract construct as well, so either an interface or (more suitably) an abstract class.  I would then situate the parts-related methods in `Vehicle` and have the concrete implementation either extend `Vehicle` if it is an abstract class or implement both `Paintable` and `Vehicle` if it is an interface.