# Scala's naming convention for traits

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a `trait` in Scala

```
trait Connection {

  def init(name: String)
  def dispose
}
```

And I want to create a class which implements it. But I want to name it as `Connection` also:

```
class Connection extends Connection {
  // ....
 }
```

It's not going to work. Of course, I could name `trait` something differently, but it turned out that the naming convention in Scala says that I should name trait as ordinary classes, meaning without any prefix, which I would use in C# (`IConnection` where  `IConnection` would be the `interface`).

And in this particular case the name of `Connection` for the `class` and the `trait` is more suitable.

Or did I miss something in Scala's naming convention?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The fact that you are extracting a general API into a `Connection` trait itself implies that it'll have multiple specific implementations. Those implementations will of course be related to some more specific entities, e.g. a MySQL or an H2 database.

There are several approaches to your problem depending on the chosen architecture of your app:

1. If you keep the specific implementations in the same namespace you get:

   - `myApp.Connection`
   - `myApp.MySqlConnection`
   - `myApp.H2Connection`
2. But the above is actually discouraged due to redundancy in names (the `*Connection` part) and introduction of a new package is recommended, e.g.:

   - `myApp.Connection`
   - `myApp.connections.MySql`
   - `myApp.connections.H2`

   or

   - `myApp.Connection`
   - `myApp.Connection.MySql`
   - `myApp.Connection.H2`

   if you choose to place the specific implemntation in a *companion object* of `Connection`.
3. In more advanced approaches to architecture you will end up with specific implementations having private packages:

   - `myApp.Connection`
   - `myApp.mySql.Connection`
   - `myApp.h2.Connection`

   And even here although you have the `Connection` name clashing it's easily solvable due to types being located in different packages by using qualified references (`myApp.Connection`) or qualified imports:

   ```
   import myApp.{Connection => GeneralConnection} //or IConnection if you insist
   ```

Comment: I think option 1 is the most common in practice. Option 2 is confusing when you're reading code.

Comment: @monkjack That's right; It may feel like repeating the same information but on the other hand you can't expect all the developers to have all the package context of all the types in their head

Answer (score 11):

It's not a convention but something used in the scala.collection is the suffix Like used in traits:

- [SeqLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.SeqLike): A template trait for sequences of type Seq[A].
- [MapLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.MapLike): A template trait for maps, which associate keys with values.

And so on.

I guess it's their way to say Rectangle/Rectangular where this relation (Seq/SeqLike) does not have a clear naming.

Answer (score 8):

In Martin Odersky's book there is a sample with a class Rectangle that extends a trait Rectangular and a class Rational that extends a trait Ordered. So the pattern seems here to be to use an adjective for the trait name an a subject for the class name. So in your case it would be "class Connection extends Connected". At least I like this more than "class ConnectionImpl extends Connection".

Comment: Maybe Connection extends Connectable.  It might not always be connected.

Answer (score 5):

The common practice for naming class that *implements* some interface/trait is to add Impl as postfix (and don't add any prefixes/postfixes to interface/trait):

```
class ConnectionImpl extends Connection {
  // ....
}
```

Why? Because in good code you [write functions against interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/298389), so you wont polute your functions with thoose I's:

```
def sendThings(conn: Connection) {


}
```

versus

```
def sendThings(conn: IConnection) {


}
```

If you have multiple implementations, this, of course should be `Connection` trait, `HttpConnection` class1, `JdbcConnection` class2.

Comment: `HttpUtilImpl`, `UserImpl`, `CarImpl`...? that is, I should add `Impl` to each class name in my code, even if there is no trait with the similar name? Not reasonable at all.

Comment: @MariusKavansky nope, only if there is *trait and one class* situation and they do not differ in names.

Comment: that's the same thing. as I said in my question, I could name the trait (or the class) differently, but I didn't want to do that.

Comment: In his book Martin Odersky has a sample of a trait Rectangular where a class Rectangle extends the trait Rectangular. I like this Rectangle->Rectangular naming pair. What I would like to have is a naming convention that is a generalisation of Rectangle->Rectangular. But that is hard to find. To me the solution with Impl is ugly. I also didn't like it in the Java world.

Comment: +1 for the link and adding extra affixes to "private/hidden" part of code rather than to "public".

Comment: I don't like Impl too, but sometimes very difficult to find equivalents of "Rectangle->Rectangular" kind, or "legal" name of class may be too much verbose. Of course, both cases are smells of bad understanding of domain...