# Can I have a Class and Interface with same name in same namespace?

Tags: c#, class, interface

I was assigned on a project (C# based) to work on, and i found there is a class and interface with same name in the same namespace [class : Payment, Interface : Payment]. so when i build the solution it gives me error that it is not allowed.

Renaming one of them will affect other many areas in the solution. Actually I don't know how was it working!!

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: It is customary to have interface names to start with the capital letter `I`, such as `IPayment`. This is exactly to avoid conflicts like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to have two types with the same name under the same namespace (this is one reason why namespaces are useful).

A good convention is to have the letter `I` before interface names, see: [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), [ISerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx)...

If you must keep the identical names, you may change the `namespace` of one of the types and change the `using namespace` declaration accordingly.

Comment: Note that if you *need* namespaces to avoid name clashes, then maybe your names are bad.

Comment: Absolutely, I see no reason to have the same type name, especially for a class and an interface.

Comment: I was confused with the naming too, but i will change the interface name to IPayment. and change all affected areas. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice explanation for your question. It's about Java but I think best practices can be similar about naming.

[Java Interfaces/Implementation naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814805/java-interfaces-implementation-naming-convention)

Answer (score 0):

I also got an old project with this issue, where the same name is used for an Interface and a class in the same namespace.

It was in .net 4.5, but I don't remember any .net framework ever allowed this.

I am too very surprised, at how this was working earlier. Will investigate more and come back here for the knowledge base.