# Java aop ComponentScan not working & AnnotationConfigApplicationContext getBean not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I wrote a simple set of classes to show a friend about using Annotations for AOP (instead of xml config) . We couldnt get the @ComponentScan to work AND AnnotationConfigApplicationContext getBean too misbehaves. I wanted to understand two things . See Code below :

PersonOperationsI.java

```
package samples.chapter3;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public interface PersonOperationsI {

    public String getName();

}
```

PersonOperations.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
package samples.chapter3;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PersonOperations implements PersonOperationsI {


    public String getName() {
        return "";
    }

}
```

PersonOperationsConfigClass.java

```
package samples.chapter3;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
//question2  - Below Component Scan didnt work - Test Case failing in setup()
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"samples.chapter3"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy

public class PersonOperationsConfigClass {

}
```

PersonOperationsAdvice.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
package samples.chapter3;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class PersonOperationsAdvice {

    /**
     * execution( [Modifiers] [ReturnType] [FullClassName].[MethodName]
    ([Arguments]) throws [ExceptionType])

     * @param joinPoint
     * @return
     */
    @Before("execution(public * samples.chapter3.PersonOperations.getName()))")
    public String beforeGetName(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("method name = " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        return null;
    }
}
```

PersonOperationsTest.java

```
package samples.chapter3;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { PersonOperationsConfigClass.class })
public class PersonOperationsTest {

    //@Autowired
    private PersonOperationsI obj;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.scan("samples.chapter3");
        ctx.refresh();
        obj = ctx.getBean(PersonOperationsI.class);
//obj = ctx.getBean(PersonOperations.class);//getBean of Child class not working - why ?

        Assert.assertNotNull(obj);
        ctx.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(obj.getName());
    }

}
```

Question1 - Why @componentscan doesnt work .If I dont use AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  in test case and just rely on @componentscan & autowired - the object in test case is null

Question2 - ctx.getBean(PersonOperations.class);//getBean of Child class not working - why ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to annotate your Interface with `@Component`?

Comment: it was just a trial - I removed it ..

Answer (score 4):

**A1** , `@ComponentScan` didn't work because it is commented out from the ["The component classes to use for loading an ApplicationContext."](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html#classes--) or `PersonOperationsConfigClass`

```
@Configuration
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"samples.chapter3"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy

public class PersonOperationsConfigClass {}
```

The test class gets the ApplicationContext created from the component classes specified with the [@ContextConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) annotation. Since no components were created or auto detected , `@Autowired` failed.

When `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` was used within a method annotated with `@Before` , an ApplicationContext was programmatically created.`ctx.scan("samples.chapter3");` scanned and auto-deteced `PersonOperations` annotated with `@Component`. `obj` reference got set with the code `obj = ctx.getBean(PersonOperationsI.class);`. This object was not *'Autowired'*.

**Update based on the comment from OP**

The Junit 4 annotations and the @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) combination is not working for me.

Following Test class runs successfully with zero errors/failures. `obj` is autowired and not null. I have used the corresponding [annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-beforeall#beforeeach-and-beforeall) from Junit 5.

```
package rg.app.aop.so.q1;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {PersonOperationsConfigClass.class})
public class PersonOperationsTest {

    @Autowired
    private PersonOperationsI obj;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("init ::"+ obj);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(obj);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPersonOps() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(obj);
    }
}
```

Configuration class

```
package rg.app.aop.so.q1;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"rg.app.aop.so.q1"})
public class PersonOperationsConfigClass {

}
```

---

**A2,**
Following are my analysis.

Remember , `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` has got a default value "false" for `proxyTargetClass` attribute. This attribute determines the proxying mechanism : JDK proxy (false) or CGLIB proxy (true) .

Here the presence of a valid Aspect with a valid advice results in the actual proxying to kick in. A component will get proxied only when the advice has any effect on it. In short , the proxying of a Component happens only if required.

**Case 1**

When : `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` / `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = false )`

- `ctx.getBean(InterfaceType)` returns a bean
- `ctx.getBean(ImplementationClassType)` fails to return a bean

**Case 2**

When : `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true )`

- `ctx.getBean(InterfaceType)` returns a bean
- `ctx.getBean(ImplementationClassType)` returns a bean

**Case 3**

When : `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation is absent

- `ctx.getBean(InterfaceType)` returns a bean
- `ctx.getBean(ImplementationClassType)` returns a bean

**Case 1** , Spring AOP is enabled with `proxyTargetClass` as false. JDK proxy creates a proxy bean of Interface type. 
The bean created is of type *InterfaceType* and not *ImplementationClassType* . This explains why ctx.getBean(ImplementationClassType) fails to return a bean.

**Case 2** , Spring AOP is enabled with `proxyTargetClass` as true . CGLIB creates a proxy bean by subclassing the class annotated with `@Component`.
The bean created is of type *ImplementationClassType* , as well qualifies as *InterfaceType*. So both the getBean() calls returns this bean successfully.

**Case 3**,

Spring only create "proxy" objects if any special processing is required ( eg: AOP , Transaction Management ).

Now with this logic ,  since `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` is absent , a bean gets created for class annotated with `@Component` without any proxying.
The bean created is of type *ImplementationClassType* , as well qualifies as *InterfaceType*. So both the getBean() calls returns this bean successfully.

Analysis done with the following code.

```
package rg.app.aop.so.q1;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class AppMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.scan("rg.app.aop.so.q1");
        ctx.refresh();
        System.out.println();
        for(String name:ctx.getBeanNamesForType(PersonOperationsI.class)) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        for(String name:ctx.getBeanNamesForType(PersonOperations.class)) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        PersonOperationsI obj = ctx.getBean(PersonOperationsI.class);
        System.out.println(obj.getClass());

        obj = ctx.getBean(PersonOperations.class);
        System.out.println(obj.getClass());
        ctx.registerShutdownHook();

    }

}
```

Case 1 prints

```
personOperations
class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'rg.app.aop.so.q1.PersonOperations' available
```

Case 2 prints

```
personOperations
personOperations
class rg.app.aop.so.q1.PersonOperations$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c179e7f2
class rg.app.aop.so.q1.PersonOperations$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c179e7f2
```

Case 3 prints

```
personOperations
personOperations
class rg.app.aop.so.q1.PersonOperations
class rg.app.aop.so.q1.PersonOperations
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you . Any more clarification required on A1 ?

Comment: yes . I ran the whole test after uncommenting COmponentScan and Autowire didnt work (still object is null ) . Something else is missing ?

Comment: PersonOperationsConfigClass.java     `package samples.chapter3;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"samples.chapter3"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy

public class PersonOperationsConfigClass {

}
` PersonOperationsTest.java `@Before
 public void setUp() {

  
  Assert.assertNotNull(obj);//still null pointer here 
  
 }`

Comment: What is your junit version and how are your running the tests ?. The junit annotations seems to be from junit 4 and @ExtendWith is for junit 5 .

Comment: "Spring only create "proxy" objects if any special processing is required ( eg: AOP , Transaction Management )." What about the @Lookup method? it seems it always creates a CGLIB proxy.

Answer (score 1):

1. Usually you should use `@ComponentScan` along with a `@Configuration` annotated class and keep in mind that ***@ComponentScan* without arguments tells Spring to scan the current package and all of its sub-packages.**.
2. The **@Component** class tells Spring to create a bean of that type so you no longer need to use xml configuration, and the bean is a class that can be instantiated => no interface / abstract classes. So, in your case, you should remove the **@Component** from `PersonOperationsI` and leave it only in `PersonOperations`. When you annotate a class with **@Component**, the default name given to the bean is the class name with lower first letter, so you should call `ctx.getBean("personOperationsI")` or `ctx.getBean(PersonOperations.class)`

And for the future read these [naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814805/java-interfaces-implementation-naming-convention) for interfaces and implementations. In your case I would modify the following :
`PersonOperationsI` to `Operations`

Answer (score 1):

> **Question 2**

As you said, bean scanning process was **not complete**, so there is **no bean** in **context** and you should not expect any bean from context, Either `@Autowired` way or `context.getBean` way.(Both ways return **null** )

Below link has more information on bean scanning(It may help)

**[Spring Component Scanning](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning)**