# How Bean light mode configuration creates proxy on beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I read a part of spring doc about @Bean Lite mode [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) 
As I understand, if config is annotated as component then spring doesn't create proxy class of this config and all configured beans inside this class are treated as plain method calls. However, according to this example, Spring created proxy for bean annotated as **@Transactional** and configured inside **@Component** class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TranslatorApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ProxyBean bean;

    @Autowired
    Conf conf;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TranslatorApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public final void run(final String... args) {
        System.out.println(conf.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(bean.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Component
    static class Conf {
        @Bean
        public ProxyBean bean() {
            return new ProxyBean();
        }
    }

    static class ProxyBean {

        @Transactional
        public void init() {

        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Conf
TranslatorApplication$ProxyBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f4c1a493
```

Which means that ProxyBean is a proxy created by CGLIB.
The question is, if configuration class is not a proxy then how Spring created a proxy for method `public ProxyBean bean()` ?
Spring Boot version - 2.1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain

> if config is annotated as component then spring doesn't create proxy
>   class of this config

Spring container creates proxy for a bean only if it is required , like for any special processing for the bean e.g: AOP , Transaction Management. I have explained this for another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59770104/4214241) , please go through A2 section of the answer if interested.

So for example , the `Conf` class bean will be a proxy if the class is annotated with `@Transactional`.

> all configured beans inside this class are treated as plain method
>   calls

Not correct. All the self invocation or internal method calls in a *Lite* mode are plain method calls in contrast to the *special processing* within a class annotated with `@Configuration`. In a `@Configuration` annotated class , multiple calls to a `@Bean` annotated method returns the same bean instance.

From the documentation of [@Bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)

> In contrast to the semantics for bean methods in @Configuration
>   classes, 'inter-bean references' are not supported in lite mode.
>   Instead, when one @Bean-method invokes another @Bean-method in lite
>   mode, the invocation is a standard Java method invocation; Spring does
>   not intercept the invocation via a CGLIB proxy. This is analogous to
>   inter-@Transactional method calls where in proxy mode, Spring does not
>   intercept the invocation — Spring does so only in AspectJ mode.

So the observation that

> Spring created proxy for bean annotated as @Transactional and
>   configured inside @Component class

is as expected for the reasons

1. A class annotated with `@Transactional` needs proxying
2. A class annotated with `@Component` does not require any special processing in this example

I have modified your example to explain this better

Notable changes are

1. Annotating `@Component` annotated class with `@Transactional` to explain the proxying.
2. Adding a `@Configuration` class to explain the  'inter-bean references' support
3. No `@Transactional` for `ConfigurationBean.init()` method to explain the proxying.

Code

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TranslatorApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ComponentBean beanOne;

    @Autowired
    ComponentBean beanTwo;

    @Autowired
    ComponentConf conf;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurationBean beanThree;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurationBean beanFour;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurationConf config;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TranslatorApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public final void run(final String... args) {
        System.out.println(conf+" : "+conf.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(beanOne+" : "+beanOne.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(beanTwo+" : "+beanTwo.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(config+" : "+config.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(beanThree+" : "+beanThree.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(beanFour+" : "+ beanFour.getClass().getSimpleName());   
    }

    interface ComponentConfIntf{}

    @Component
    @Transactional
    static class ComponentConf{
        @Bean
        public ComponentBean beanOne() {
            return new ComponentBean();
        }

        @Bean
        public ComponentBean beanTwo() {
            return beanOne();
        }
    }

    static class ComponentBean {

        @Transactional
        public void init() {

        }
    }

    @Configuration
    static class ConfigurationConf {
        @Bean
        public ConfigurationBean beanThree() {
            return new ConfigurationBean();
        }

        @Bean
        public ConfigurationBean beanFour() {
            return beanThree();
        }
    }

    static class ConfigurationBean {

        public void init() {

        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
rg.xx.xx.TranslatorApplication$ComponentConf@8a589a2 : TranslatorApplication$ComponentConf$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e204f764
rg.xx.xx.TranslatorApplication$ComponentBean@c65a5ef : TranslatorApplication$ComponentBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d3d05c88
rg.xx.xx.TranslatorApplication$ComponentBean@6b5176f2 : TranslatorApplication$ComponentBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d3d05c88
rg.xx.xx.TranslatorApplication$ConfigurationConf$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9369a982@b672aa8 : TranslatorApplication$ConfigurationConf$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9369a982
rg.xx.xx.TranslatorApplication$ConfigurationBean@2fab4aff : ConfigurationBean
rg.xx.xx.TranslatorApplication$ConfigurationBean@2fab4aff : ConfigurationBean
```

Do note that

1. `ComponentConf` bean is proxied.
2. `ComponentBean` returns two different bean instances due to *Lite* mode.
3. `ConfigurationBean` returns the same instance.
4. `ConfigurationBean` instances are not proxied.

There is an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919004/4214241) by @kriegaex on the working of a `@Configuration` class. Do read.

Hope this helps.