# Is a proxy created for each Bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

So, I was reading online and you cannot make Configuration final because CGLIB extends the class to create a proxy. However, I was reading the documentation for @Scope, and the default proxyMethod value is that no proxy is created (link here- https://docs.spring.io/springframework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html).

So, my main question is, is a proxy created for each @Configuration?

Comment: scoping and proxying are totally different things. When needed for a scope a proxy is created for a scope but not for a singleton or application scoped bean. Even a singleton might be proxied based on other Aspects (like transactions, retrying etc.). An `@Configuration` class **might** be proxied depended on the `proxyBeanMethods` attribute (which defaults to `true`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring creates proxy for a bean only if required ( example:Transaction management). I have explained this for another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59770104/4214241) , please go through A2 section of the answer for more details.

For a `@Configuration` annotated class a proxy will always be created , which implies that it is required. Why it is required can be understood from the following references.

[`@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) : Read through sections *@Bean Methods in @Configuration Classes* and *@Bean Lite Mode*

Do read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919004/4214241) excellent answer from @kriegaex to understand the inner workings of `@Configuration` class.

So to answer your question *is a proxy created for each @Configuration* ? Yes , unless the [`proxyBeanMethods`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html#proxyBeanMethods--) for `@Configuration` is configured explicity.

Hope this helps.