# Meaning of the prefix I in Java-Classnames

Tags: java

While browsing some java-repositories I stumbled upon Class which had the Prefix `I` to their names.

For example i found the class `IPlayer` and i could not figgure out what this I shall mean.

Comment: Generally, I stands for [Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html). Some developer prefix the names of interfaces with an uppercase I to underline that this type is an interface.

Comment: Probably interface.

Comment: The problem is, it "could" stand for anything, however, many developers "tend" to use it when defining `interface`s, just like you sometime see `SomClassImpl` which tends to mean "the implementation of said interface"

Comment: It means that the person does not use the general Java conventions, which discourage repeating type information in the name.

Comment: Means too much exposure to Microsoft COM conventions :-)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814805/java-interfaces-implementation-naming-convention

Comment: Also see [Should interface names begin with an “I” prefix?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/117348/should-interface-names-begin-with-an-i-prefix).

Comment: More fatuous SO closure reasons, I see.  How can the question "require more focus"?  It is absolutely precise in what it is asking.  I could agree it's not really a great question, but lack of focus is not the reason.

Comment: It implies the type is an Interface; however, it's actually not a Java convention; rather a C# one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a naming convention some people use to name interfaces. `IPlayer` means interface for Player. I stands for Interface

Answer (score 0):

This means that this class is an [interface](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_interface.asp). It is a convention used for this identification.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Could have figured that out myself.

Comment:  Personally, I don't think I'd call it a "standard", I'd be hesitant to call it a "convention" as, as far as I know (which isn't much), it's not documented anywhere and the core libraries don't tend to use it (but the core libraries don't always follow documented convention :P) - It is a "common practice" among "some" developers, but I don't think it's one that "everyone" is expected to follow ... just saying ;)

Comment: I thought about "convention", "common practice", but ended up wrongly writing "standard". In the end, that's right.

Comment: But it's not a convention in actual Java.  Java has Collection, List, Map, Set, etc.,  and not one of them starts with "I",