# c# - type used as a variable

Tags: c#

I have a simple business manager facade that should just persist some inventory information.  However I keep getting the error that "Home.Services.InventorySvc" is a type being used as a variable.

My facade code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Home.Domain;
using Home.Services;

namespace Home.Business
{
    public class InventoryMngr
    {
        public void Create(CreateInventory inv) 
        {
            Factory factory = Factory.GetInstance();
            InventorySvc invSvc =
            (InventorySvc)factory.GetService(
            (InventorySvc).Name);
            invSvc.CreateInventory(inv);
        }
    }
}
```

The InventorySvc code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Home;
using Home.Domain;

namespace Home.Services
{
    public interface InventorySvc : IService
    {
        void CreateInventory(CreateInventory createinventory);
    }
}
```

Comment: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) so we can't use it on new questions unfortunately

Comment: Look at `(InventorySvc).Name` (since this was originally tagged as homework). Presumably, this should be a string from somewhere. You are using the type name, rather than an instance, so there is no object from which to retrieve the Name property.

Comment: yep, the factory.GetService call looks suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `(InventorySvc).Name` which is the same as `InventorySvc.Name`, so that would be accessing a static member of the `InventorySvc` class. As it's not a class but an interface, it can't have static members.

Comment: Maybe that should be `typeof(InventorySvc).Name`. While `InventorySvc` can't be used as a "variable", `typeof(InventorySvc)` gives an object of type `System.Type`, and `System.Type` does have an instance property called `Name` (which it inherits from its base class `System.Reflection.MemberInfo`).

Answer (score 1):

```
InventorySvc invSvc = (InventorySvc)factory.GetService((InventorySvc).Name);
```

This code should retrieve an instance of a type which implements `InventorySvc`. However, it looks like you are attempting to *pass* an instance of the type, which wouldn't make sense--the syntax is wrong and you haven't yet instantiated the type. Presumably, you don't even *know* the specific type yet, just the interface type. The factory and the interface have abstracted the implementation (usually a good thing).

In your example, the factory probably expects the name of the type as a string (I won't overcomplicate the answer by debating if that is a good thing or not). In return, the factory will instantiate an instance which implements `InventorySvc` and return it. Only then can you invoke instance members such as the "Name" property.

As a side note, interface names [should start with an `I` in c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bc1fexb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), e.g. `IInventorySvc`. This makes it much clearer to you and anyone who reads your code that it is an interface.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/681815/453277