# about Variable name member prefixes

Tags: c#, java, c++, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should (or shouldn't) I prefix fields with 'm_' in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659552/why-should-or-shouldnt-i-prefix-fields-with-m-in-c)

I am reading CLEAN CODE

there is one paragraph about member prefixed.

THe author suggests not using m_ anymore.
such as:

```
public class Part{
  private String m_dsc;
  void setName(String name){
    m_dsc - name;
  }
}
```

should be:

```
public class Part{
  String description;
  void setDescription(String description){
    this.description = description'
  }
}
```

My question is, why we use m_ before?

And, this book is using Java as an example.
Is this suggestion good for c# ? what about c++

Thank you!

Comment: thank you you two. very usefle information. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The m_ prefix makes it easy to differentiate member variables with local variables or parameters.

This is valid for classes in object oriented languages (so, yes C#, C++, etc.)

Now, with the advances in IDEs, the m_ prefix doesn't seem to be as useful though (in the case where you're wondering if a variable is a class member or not, it's easy and fast to go to definition.)

Comment: In OOP languages like C# or Java there is absolutely no need to prefix it with `m_` or `_`. If you need to distinguish it as a member variable you should use the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 4):

`m_` is variant of Hungarian notation - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation.

Using it or not is personal/team call, but the recommendation to not to use prefixes for fields is a long standing one for C# - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx .